# Compile binaries to multiple versions of .NET Framework using Bazel

Tags: c#, .net, bazel

How does one use the [.NET build rules for Bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_dotnet) to build versions of the same library for different versions of the .NET Framework? For library developers, this is a [common thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget) to do when distributing libraries via, say, NuGet, in that the package will have multiple binaries, one for each targeted version of a platform.

Currently, it's possible to specify a version of the .NET Framework using the `dotnet_register_toolchains` workspace rule in a `WORKSPACE` file. However, this will only allow use of one version of the framework at a time. If it's possible to register individual toolchains to make this work in the .NET build rules, such a thing is not at all well-documented, nor are there any easily findable examples from which one might extract a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not yet supported. Only one version of .NET Framework, or Mono, or .NET Core per workspace is supported.

Comment: That makes Bazel unusable for my project. Thanks for the definitive answer.